# What is a type of a resulting variable when NetworkImage or FileImage can be reterned?

Tags: flutter, dart

What is a type of `image` here?

```
final image =
    imagePath.contains('https://') ? NetworkImage(imagePath) : FileImage(File(imagePath));
```

usage:

```
child: Ink.image(
    image: image as ImageProvider,
```

Comment: just print the run time type - `Print(image.runTimeType);`

Comment: NetworkImage type is NetworkImage and the other one is FileImage... but they both can be used in Ink.image without using as ImageProvider..... what is the error?

Comment: The *static* type of `image` is the common base class of `NetworkImage` and `FileImage`, which would be `Object`.

Comment: @veneno The *runtime* type doesn't tell you anything about what the *static* type of the variable is.

Comment: It's probably surprising that the common base class isn't `ImageProvider<Object>` or `ImageProvider<dynamic>` since `NetworkImage` and `FileImage` are each implicitly convertible to those types.  Perhaps worth filing a Dart language bug if there isn't one already.

Answer (score 0):

**NetworkImage** and **FileImage** are both extending ImageProvider interface.

You can do your cast here :

```
final ImageProvider image = imagePath.contains('https://') ? NetworkImage(imagePath) : FileImage(File(imagePath)) as ImageProvider
```

and

```
child: Ink.image(
    image: image,
```

*image* type will be NetworkImage or FileImage before cast.

Comment: Did you try it?  I don't think `final ImageProvider image = condition? NetworkImage(...) : FileImage(...);` will pass analysis if implicit downcasts are disabled.

Comment: You're right, I've forgot to add "as ImageProvider" at the end

Comment: "image type will be NetworkImage or FileImage before cast." it means that `image` type is dynamic